# I want to parse xml comming from http server using blackberry

Tags: blackberry, xmlpullparser

I want to parse xml which coming from http server using black berry

Comment: have u searched xml parsing in stack overflow using SAX Parser?

Comment: This question is duplicated often.  Among them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461711/how-to-parse-xml-document-in-blackberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [KXML](http://kxml.objectweb.org/software/downloads/) framework and parse the incoming data from server. For more information see this [wiki link](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_parse_an_XML_file_in_Java_ME_with_kXML).

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the code.. visit the below link.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461711/how-to-parse-xml-document-in-blackberry/6936613#6936613)!
This works with [reference links](http://www.codinguru.com/) as well.